# ExtJS 4.2.1 Treeview nodes are messed up after component is re-rendered

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am working on a bugfixing after upgrade from 4.1.1 to 4.2.1 and have been stucked up with a treeview for a while now.

How the component looks after the application is started for first time (or after page refresh):

[image: expected look]

The problem description: the main screen has a treeview on the left (categories) and a grid on the rest of screen (with products). After I first open the screen, the categories within a tree are displayed as expected. But when I click on a reload button it loads the tree store and grid store again - and here some categories are doubled (I guess all the second level nodes are doubled). The AJAX request returns the same data - on each request.

[image: subcategories are doubled]

And even weirder case: if I open another component and then come back to this screen, the categories are rendered totally messed up.

[image: even more messed up...]

Here is the JSON response (all the time the same):

```json
{
    "user":{},
    "data":{
        "children":[
            {
                "category_apps":[{"name":"default text", "domain_id":"17"}],
                "expanded":false,
                "expandable":false,
                "id":"category_with_unassigned_products",
                "logo":"",
                "children":[]},
            {
                "category_apps":[{"category_id":"8390","domain_id":"17","is_active":"1","name":"main category","name_type":"TEXT","url_path":"\/main-category"}],
                "category_id":"8390",
                "level":0,
                "event_id":"1331",
                "expanded":true,
                "expandable":false,
                "id":"main_category",
                "logo":"\/media\/\/event\/1331\/categories\/8390_1376315425.jpg",
                "image":"\/event\/1331\/categories\/8390_1376315425.jpg",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "expanded":true,
                        "category_id":"8598",
                        "expandable":false,
                        "logo":"\/media\/\/event\/1331\/categories\/8598_1376315425.jpg",
                        "image":"\/event\/1331\/categories\/8598_1376315425.jpg",
                        "level":"1",
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "expanded":false,
                                "category_id":"8599",
                                "expandable":false,
                                "logo":"\/media\/\/event\/1331\/categories\/8599_1376315425.jpg",
                                "image":"\/event\/1331\/categories\/8599_1376315425.jpg",
                                "level":"2",
                                "children":[],
                                "category_apps":[{"category_id":"8599","domain_id":"17","is_active":"1","name":"sub subcategory","name_type":"TEXT","url_path":"\/main-category\/main\/sub-subcategory"}]
                            }
                        ],
                        "category_apps":[{"category_id":"8598","domain_id":"17","is_active":"1","name":"main subcategory","name_type":"TEXT","url_path":"\/main-category\/main-subcategory"}]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the code responsible for appending child nodes - but after debugging I know that after the second child of the root (see JSON above) is processed, the nodes in the tree are immediately shown doubled and/or messed up at once...

```js
appendChildToRecord: function(child, record, store)
{
    var data = {};
    data[store.proxy.reader.root] = child;
    var newRecords = store.proxy.reader.read(data).records;
    record.appendChild(newRecords);
    return newRecords[0];
}
```

Any idea, thought and help is highly appreciated!

**UPDATE**: If I switch the ExtJS back to version **4.1.1** the tree is always loading properly - therefore It is clear the problems occurred only after switch to version 4.2.1. And I cannot even reveal the problem when debugging - at certain point the whole node subtree for the main_category is rendered at once and messed up...

**UPDATE 2**: by debugging of whole tree-build process I have found up that on re-load the categories and it's children are processed in wrong order. By processed I mean these steps are taken:

1. get first level first category
2. add to the root
3. process `children` (recursive, starts at point 1.)
4. remove `children` from the source for that category

While on first load the categories are processed in the right order

1. category 1st lvl
2. category 1st lvl

   1. category 2nd lvl

      1. category 3rd lvl
   2. category 2nd lvl

      1. category 3rd lvl
      2. ...

on the second and each other load (without refreshing of the browser window) the order is changed - the second category of first level is processed as last one, therefore the second level categories are added once again and therefore they are doubled.

So the question is: **why is the categories (nodes / records) order changed when re-loading of the store?** I am sure and checked it that the JSON response is not changed and is always the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After additional hours of really deep debugging I have found out that the root node (the one defined within the store) is keeping it's previous state, thus `expanded` property remains `true` within each next re-load attempt.

This was causing problems with the first level category - as ExtJS thought it is already visible (added to the expanded root) and advanced to processing directly the children. Therefore the second first level category was processed as last - it's *not deleted* children were added (appended) again.

**Fix:** before each `tree.store.load();` I have to set the root's `expanded` property to false:

```js
tree.getRootNode().set('expanded', false);

tree.store.load({
    //...
});
```

Hope this could help somebody who may run into the same problem...

This fixes both the problems I had - one when reloading the store via button and one when reloading the whole component.